# XML PHP Delete specific Child if?

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml document looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<library>
  <invites>
    <invite>
      <username>0</username>
      <userid>0</userid>
    </invite>
    <invite>
      <username>Danielle</username>
      <gameid>87808</gameid>
    </invite>
    <invite>
      <username>Petra</username>
      <userid>978</userid>
    </invite>
  </invites>
</library>
```

Now, I want to delete the `<invite>` with Danielle but I am not sure how? I am using this right now but this will only delete the first record?

```
$file = 'my.xml';
$fp = fopen($file, "rb") or die("cannot open file");
$str = fread($fp, filesize($file));

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->loadXML($str) or die("Error");

$root   = $xml->documentElement;
$fnode  = $root->firstChild;

$ori    = $fnode->childNodes->item(0);

$fnode->removeChild($ori);

$xml->save($file);
```

I want to be able to delete depending on either gameid or userid. How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use XPath to select all nodes that have a certain userid or gameid: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

Comment: Yes, I know how to delete one node with XPath:

<gameid>87808</gameid>

But I want to be able to delete all this:

<invite>
   <username>Danielle</username>
   <gameid>87808</gameid>
</invite>

Not sure how to do so?

Comment: (out the top of my head) This would be an XPath expression like `/invite/username[text()='Danielle']/gameid[text()='87808']`. Follow some XPath tutorials and experiment!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Using DOM & DOMXPath.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

// load the xml file
$dom->loadXML( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<library>
  <invites>
    <invite>
      <username>0</username>
      <userid>0</userid>
    </invite>
    <invite>
      <username>Danielle</username>
      <gameid>87808</gameid>
    </invite>
    <invite>
      <username>Petra</username>
      <userid>978</userid>
    </invite>
  </invites>
</library>', LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//find all 'invite' nodes with username=Danielle and delete'em.
$node = $xpath->query("//invite[username='Danielle']");

// if found, append the new "value" node
if( $node->length ) {
    foreach ($node as $n) {
        $n->parentNode->removeChild( $n );
    }
}

header('content-type: text/xml');
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JesperMansa - Glad to know it helped you. Please accept my answer as the correct one if it helps you.